How to store all Go templates in a single *Template variable?
Currently, I have a map[string]*template.Template, which stores each individual template. I load them like so:
func Load(templates fs.FS) (map[string]*template.Template, error) {
  pages := []string{"home", "login", "signup", "dashboard"}  
  partials := []string{"account-form", "user-details"}

  tmpls := make(map[string]*template.Template)

  for _, page := range pages {
    tmpl := template.New("layout.tmpl")

    tmpl, err := tmpl.ParseFS(templates, "layouts/layout.tmpl", "pages/"+page+".tmpl")
    if err != nil {
      return nil, err
    }

    for _, partial := range partials {
      tmpl, err = tmpl.ParseFS(templates, "partials/"+partial+".tmpl")
      if err != nil {
        return nil, err
      }
    }

    tmpls[page] = tmpl
  }

  return tmpls, nil
}

This does the job, since I can then execute a template like so: tmpls["home"].Execute(w, data).
However, I'm not sure this is the most efficient way of doing this. I read you can hold it all in a single *template.Template variable.
I tried doing something like:
func Load(templates fs.FS) (*template.Template, error) {
  tmpl, err := template.New("layout").ParseFS(templates, "layouts/layout.tmpl", "pages/*.tmpl", "partials/*.tmpl")
  return tmpl, err
}

// somewhere else
// executing template
tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "home.tmpl", data)

But all I got is a blank page.
Here is what my layout.tmpl file looks like:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo=">
    <title>{{ block "page-title" . }} Some Website {{ end }}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <header>...</header>
  <main>{{ template "main" . }}</main>
  <footer>...</footer>
</body>

Here is what my home.tmpl file looks like:
{{ define "main" }}
<section>Some content...</section>
{{ end }}

How can I achieve this? Any help is appreciated.

What you read is incorrect.  A *template.Template is limited to one template per name.  For example, a template cannot contain a "main" for each of home, login, etc.  Use the current code or improve that code by loading the common templates once and cloning the comment templates for each page.

@CeriseLimón, I see. Thanks for the clarification. Do you mind sharing how I could improve the existing code? I was thinking of doing tmpl, err := tmpl.ParseFS(templates, "layouts/layout.tmpl", "pages/"+page+".tmpl", "partials/*.tmpl") and scrapping the partials loop. Any other suggestions?

base := template.ParseFS(templates, “layout/layout.html”, “partials/*.html”); for page := range pages { templs[page] = base.Clone(); templs[page].ParseFS(templates, “page/“ + page + .html”) }.   The code in this comment omits error handling, but your actual code should check for parse errors.

Simply use template.ParseGlob to add all the templates in the template directory to your base template.
base.tmpl
{{define "content"}}
  <h2>Content Section</h2>
  <p>This is the content section of the page.</p>
{{end}}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Web Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Welcome to My Web Page</h1>
  <p>This is a basic HTML template.</p>
  {{template "content"}}
  {{template "footer"}}
</body>
</html>

Note the {{ template "footer" }} directive.
templates/footer.tmpl
{{define "footer"}}
  <footer>
    <p>© 2024 My Web Page. All rights reserved.</p>
  </footer>
{{end}}

main.go
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    var (
        tmpl *template.Template
        err  error
    )

    // Get a list of all files ending in .tmpl
    if tmpl, err = template.ParseFiles("base.tmpl"); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Add all files ending in .tmpl in the templates directory
    if tmpl, err = tmpl.ParseGlob("templates/*.tmpl"); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    log.Printf("%s\n", tmpl.DefinedTemplates())

    if err = tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "base.tmpl", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

Output:
2024/06/09 14:29:43 ; defined templates are: "content", "base.tmpl", "footer", "footer.tmpl"

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Web Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Welcome to My Web Page</h1>
  <p>This is a basic HTML template.</p>
  
  <h2>Content Section</h2>
  <p>This is the content section of the page.</p>

  
  <footer>
    <p>© 2024 My Web Page. All rights reserved.</p>
  </footer>

</body>
</html>


This answer does not solve OP's problem.  The OP has several templates in the pages/ directory containing {{ define "main" }}.  template.ParseGlob(fs, "pages/*") will overwrite all but one of the pages.

True. However, we might be able to adapt that in the handler, loading the files conditionally. Will try to adapt tomorrow, it is late here.

Note that the question has code that works.
